# For a simple graph of girth 5 and with minimum degree $k$ has at least $k^2+1$ vertices.

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, induction

I know this problem can be done directly but I have tried this using Induction. I want your help in understanding where my proof is wrong.

**Proof:** We will use induction on **n** (*number of vertices of the graph*)

**Base step :** The graph with the least number of vertices and a girth of 5 is 5-cycle $C_5$. So, we consider this as a base case, as the minimum degree is 2 and clearly $2^2+1 \leq 5$. So base case is satisfied.

**Hypothesis :** Let this statement be true for all graph having $n-1$ vertices and a girth of 5.

**Induction Step :** Let G be a graph with n vertices and a girth of 5.

Consider the **5-cycle in G**. Now if none of the vertices in this cycle is having other neighbors apart from the cycle itself then we get the base case i.e. 5-cycle itself.

So let $u$ be the vertex in this 5-cycle that has another neighbor, say $v$, that is not in this cycle. (If this is in the cycle then girth will be less than 5)

**Case 1 :** If $v$ is the vertex with the least degree then removing $v$ will definitely not decrease the minimum degree of the graph and using the induction hypothesis on $G-v$ we are done. (Same hold if $v$ is not attached to the vertex of minimum degree)

**Case 2 :** If $v$ is attached to the vertex with the minimum degree.

If the minimum degree is $\leq 2$ then we are done as this graph definitely has more than 5 vertices.

If the minimum degree is $> 2$ then there must be anther vertex attached to the selected 5-cycle other than $v$, say $v'$, then we remove this vertex and similar to case 1 we are done.

*Note: disconnection will not affect the result.*

*Please help me to find the mistake if any in the above proof. Thankyou*

Comment: I think the mistake is when the minimum degree is $>2$, why there must be another vertex attached to the cycle? If $u$ has a neighbor $v$ and $v$ has a degree of $3$ or more, so.. ?

Comment: @LO2A When the minimum degree is more than 2 then clearly **each** of the vertices in the selected 5 cycle will have more than 2 neighbors. Hence for each vertex, we can select a neighbor that is not already in the cycle. (So this time we select some other vertex u' in the cycle and delete its neighbor say v'.

Comment: Oh I see, you are right, but even if so and you complete doing it, how will you reach the result, I mean if the vertex of minimal degree is not attached to any of the vertices on the cycle, can you still reach your result?

Comment: @LO2A in case 1, I have covered when v has the minimum degree (note: v is not in the cycle but a neighbor of some vertex in the cycle). Now if we find such v which is not attached to some vertex with a minimum degree then we remove v to get a graph of n-1 vertices (without decreasing least degree k and it still have girth 5) and clearly G-v will have more than $k^2+1$ vertices and G have more vertices than G-v so it will have more than $k^2+1$ vertices and hence satisfies the condition.

Comment: There are a few problems here, but you basically have to start over because you need to induct on k, not n.

Comment: There are graphs of girth 5 and minimal degree 3 such that removing any singular vertex gives a graph with minimum degree of 2, which means you can’t find your vertex to remove

Comment: Petersen graph for instance.  Does this occur for graphs that are not regular though?

Comment: @Robo300 Can you give an example of such a graph with girth 5 and minimum degree 3 such that removing any vertex gives a graph with girth 5 and minimum degree 2.

Comment: The Peterson graph is such an example. If you start with any graph with girth 5 and minimum degree at least  3, and start removing vertices in such a way that you never reduce the degree below 3, you are eventually forced to stop, and this final graph you stop at is also such an example